# Change Checkbox to Radio Button Material UI Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I am working on a React project and currently using Material Ui Data Grid for the data display.

What I want is in the table I decide whether I want the checkbox at the starting of each row or a Radio button.

Of Course the feature changes as with the radio button I can select only one data and with check box, I can select multiple data.

I can't seem to find how to do this.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this? I too am looking for a single select radio button for datagrid.

Comment: No, I had to make my own table component for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `renderCell` method in column object. You can render what you want like this:

```
{
  field: 'bypass_group_id',
  headerName: ' ',
  width: 40,
  renderCell: (cellValues) => {
    return (
      <Radio 
        checked={cellValues.id === this.state.form.selectedGroup}
        onChange={this.handleChangeRadio.bind(this,cellValues.id)}
        value={cellValues.id}
        name="radio-buttons"
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': {cellValues} }}
      />
     )
  }
}
```

[image: Img_table_example]

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using OnSelectionModelChange props of material-ui datagrid and Radio button.

**Live Demo**

[image: Edit react]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same the other day. The only way it worked for me was to use ["Data table"](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) as opposed to "datagrid". The reason is that data table's code is much more simplified and can be fiddled with.

Are your data hard-coded or shown dynamically?

I added an empty TableCell line under TableRow in my TableHead section (to basically create an empty column for the radio buttons, without a column name):

```
   <TableHead>
   <TableRow>
   <TableCell></TableCell>
   <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Age</TableCell>
   </TableHead>
   </TableRow>
```

Then in my rows section, I added a Radio component:

```
   <TableBody>
   <TableRow>
   <TableCell>
   <Radio
                      value={value}
                      checked={whatever}
                      onChange={handleRadiochange}
                      size="small"
                    />
 </TableCell>
<TableCell id="name"> John Smith </TableCell>
   <TableCell id="age"> 49 </TableCell>
```

Because my rows are generated dyamically, the  button was generated with each row. You can give it a unique {value} based on the row data (I simply chose the unique value in the row from the data I got e.g. {rowsdata.ID} or {rowsdata.SSN).

Data Table is versatile and can be modified to look like Datagrid. For example, I added AppBar (to highlight the selected row value), pagination, table-footer and hover effect.

The only thing I didn't look into was to select the the row (and the radio button) after a click (which is what happens in datagrid). This is redundant in my opinion as the end-user can as well click on the radio button and achieve the same effect.

Comment: If the columns are fixed, it can be a good solution, but unfortunately for my case I get both the rows and columns from backend. So there is no way I can use a simple data table.

Comment: You mean the number of columns changes?

Comment: Yes, I get the columns and the rows from back end

Comment: Well it's still doable because for the <tablehead> you'll add a column at the beginning for the radio buttons, and the rest of it can be used to loop through the data object/source. Thing is with datagrid, you'll have to get rid of the "select all" function as well in the tablehead.